# How to wait for entire buffer to arrive in a SSL connection

Tags: ssl, https, winsock, winsock2

I am implementing a client server program, in which the client sends HTTP messages to the server. It can be both HTTP or HTTPS
In case of large messages, like file transfer using HTTP, the client sends the whole message at one go, whereas it reaches the server in multiple fragments( the network does it). I wait for the entire message to come, and keep merging it so that I get the whole message. Content length is found using a parameter I send in the HTTP message. 
But in the case of HTTPS there is no way to know if the enitre message has arrived.
If i decrypt the fragment, it returns junk values. I think that is because, the whole encrypted message must be joined before decrypting it. 
How is it possible to identify if the entire message has arrived in HTTPs
I am using SSL library and using windows sockets.

Comment: You should be able to decrypt the stream as it arrives - it sounds like your decryption code isn't working.

Comment: @RichieHindle For small messages it works perfectly fine. Its only when large buffers arrive, it arrives in different fragments, and thats when ssl decrypt function is failing

Answer (score 2):

SSL encrypts plain data into blocks and then those blocks are transmitted individually to the other party.  The receiver needs to read the raw socket data and pump it into the SSL decryption engine as it arrives.  When the engine has enough bytes for a given block, it decrypts that block and outputs the plain data for just that block.  So you simply keep reading socket data and pumping it into the decryption engine, buffering whatever plain data is outputted, until you encounter a decrypted `<CRLF><CRLF>` sequence denoting the end of the HTTP message headers, then you process those headers to determine whether the HTTP message body is present and how it is encoded.  If a message body is present, keep reading socket data, pumping it into the decryption engine, and buffering the output plain data, until you encounter the end of the message body.  [RFC 2616 Section 4.4 - "Message Length"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4) describes how to determine the encoding of the HTTP message body (after decryption is applied) and what condition terminates the message body.

In other words, you are not supposed to look for the end of an encrypted socket message.  You are supposed to decrypt everything you receive until you detect the end of the decrypted HTTP message.

Comment: Does SSL increase or decrease the actual buffer length? From my client I am sending around 27000 bytes, which is received by my server in two fragments, 12000 and 15000, but when i do ssl_read two times, total length is about 16000! Where does the remaining data go?

Comment: SSL_read() handles the socket reading and engine pumping for you. Keep calling it until you receive the 27000 bytes of decrypted data. If you are not receiving everything you are expecting, then either the sender is not sending 27000 bytes worth of encrypted data to begin with, or you are not calling SSL_read() correctly to receive 27000 bytes of decrypted data.

Comment: My socket read() function receives the 27000 bytes of data, and it is passed to decrypt, but the output buffer is around 26000 bytes :(

Comment: Does the 27000 represent the size of the original plain data or the encrypted data? Why are you reading 27000 bytes and then decrypting them separately?  `SSL_read()` handles the reading and decrypting for you. All you have to do is provide it an output buffer to receive the decrypted data into. You are obviously doing something wrong with your code.  Please show what you are actually doing.

Comment: What I do is after i get a message from recv() function, i use Bio_Write, and then I call ssl_read. If it returns -1, I wait for more data from recv() and pass it to ssl_read() again. Till it returns a value greater than 0, i keep waiting for data on recv(). Once all data has arrived, I call multiple times ssl_read() and append the data. Is this the right way ?

Comment: Have you tried using OpenSSL without BIOs? If you associate the socket with the SSL context, `SSL_read()` does the actual reading of the socket data directly for you. But even if you use BIOs, you should call `SSL_read()` first, and when it asks for more data (reports an `OPENSSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` error) THEN you call `recv()` and `BIO_write()` to feed it more data.

Comment: I shall try without the BIOs and let you know. Could you tell what is the right way to send from the client side as well? Maybe I am wrong on that part too

Comment: I have never used BIOs myself, I always let OpenSSL do all of the socket reading/writing for me. Most OpenSSL tutorials work that way. BIOs are good if you want to do your own custom socket I/O (for example, using overlapped/IOCP socket I/O), but they are not the only option.